# mod_rewrite and keep query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to do a mod_rewrite URL transformation. I want to direct

`http://localhost/events?user=XXX&start=YYY&total=ZZZ`

to

`http://localhost/?operation=events&user=XXX&start=YYY&total=ZZZ`

What I am using currently in my `.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteRule
    ^events\?userid=([0-9]+)&start=([0-9]+)&total=([0-9]+)$
    ?operation=events&user=$1&start=$2&total=$3
    [L]
```

but it does not seem to be working.

I have also tried a simpler version:

```
RewriteRule ^events\?([a-zA-Z0-9&=]+)$ ?operation=events&$1 [L]
```

But it is also not working.

¿How can I "transfer" either the query params one by one **OR** else the whole query string to the end of the directed path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I "transfer" either the query params one by one OR else the whole query string to the end of the directed path?

This is done using `QSA` flag.  `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

However remember that you cannot match query string using `RewriteRule` directive. You can only match Request URI using `RewriteRule`.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?events/?$ ?operation=userevents [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will route `http://localhost/events` URI to `http://localhost/?operation=userevents` by **appending all the original query parameters** to rewritten URI. For example: `http://localhost/userevents?user=XXX&start=YYY&total=ZZZ` will be rewritten to `http://localhost/?operation=events&user=XXX&start=YYY&total=ZZZ`

Comment: I simplified by using the same `/events` and `?operation=events`, but actually the operation name is different than the route to call (`/events` will go to `?operation=userevents`). Could you please update proposed solution?